# The number of critical points of a rational function on the Riemann sphere

Tags: complex-analysis, rational-functions

Let $f$ be a meromorphic (equivalently, rational) function on the Riemann sphere with $k$ prescribed poles. What is the number of critical points (or critical values) of such function $f$? I believe the answer is $2k-2$, but why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know some geometry or the Riemann-Hurwitz formula,

$f$ is a degree $k$ map from $\Bbb P^1(\Bbb C)$ to $\Bbb P^1(\Bbb C)$, both surfaces have genus $0$.

Then the formula says that $2*0-2 = k(2*0-2) + n$ where $n$ is the number of critical points (in the generic case where they are all distinct so they make simple branch points)

From this you get $n = 2k-2$.

Comment: The only thing that I don't understand is why $\sum_{P\in \mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})} (e_P-1)=n$. If all $e_P$'s are simple poles, then shouldn't we have $e_P=1$ for all $P$ and hence $\sum_{P\in \mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})} (e_P-1)=0$? Probably I misunderstand the notion of ramification index... (I use the Riemann-Hurwitz formula from Wikipedia.)

Comment: $e_P$ is the ramification index of $f$ at a point $P$ in the range of $f$. It has absolutely nothing to do with any pole of $f$. For almost all $P$, $f^{-1}(P)$ is a set with $k$ elements, so $e_P = 0$ for all those points. There are only finitely many special cases where trying to solve $f(z) = P$ gives you solution with higher multiplicity, those $P$ are the branch points of $f$. In general, you will get $2k-2$ values of $P$ where solving $f(z) = P$ gives you one double solution and $k-2$ simple ones.

Answer (score 2):

For a generic degree $d$ rational map $f=P/Q$ under the conditions that (a) it is reduced, (b) that $P$ and $Q$ have same degree, (c) $Q$ has simple zeros only and (d) that $\infty$ is not a critical point, then the number of critical points is indeed $2d-2$. You may see this from $f'=(P'Q-Q'P)/Q^2$ and use the above requirements to see that the degree of the numerator is $2d-2$ and that it has no zeros in commun with $Q$. When one of the above mentioned conditions fail various other things may happen. You may look in Beardon's book on "Iteration of Rational functions".